# How to calculate profit share for this example

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education, finance

How can we calculate a profit share for Rs. 100,000 that remained in an account for 5 days only. See this question illustration below

[image: How to calculate profit]

I was confused about which tags were more appropriate for asking this question. Please re-tag the question if required. Thanks.

Comment: what does for Rs. 100,000 mean and what does that remained in the account 5 days only mean?

Comment: I meant, that amount (Rs. 1k) deposited into the account on 16th and withdrawn on 20th. Now what would be the profit sharing for Rs. 1k that remained in an account for 5 days only (out of Rs. 2500 total profit)

Comment: In other words, How much this 5 day deposit of Rs. 100,000 contributed in the month end profit?

Comment: oh, how is it compunded?

Comment: Don't know. Only the above information has been given. :)

Comment: @people who marked this question as off-topic: Help center says `... some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: Physics, engineering and financial questions ...`. If this question falls under the context of `Quantitative Finance` forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_{\rm{in}}=10,000, R_s=100,000, B_{\rm{fin}}=B_{\rm{in}}=10,000,P=2,500$. Let $\pi(R_s)$ the profit share of $R_s$.
Calling $i$ the compound monthly interest rate, you have to find $i$ such that
$$
B_{\rm{in}}(1+i)+\underbrace{R_s(1+i)^{5/30}-R_s}_{\pi(R_s)}=B_{\rm{in}}+P
$$
Solving numerically, you'll find $i\approx 9.6\%$. So the profit share of $R_s$ for 5 days is $$\pi(R_s)=R_s(1+i)^{5/30}-R_s\approx 1,539.81$$

Note that the profit share of $B_{\rm{in}}$ is $$\pi(B_{\rm{in}})=B_{\rm{in}}(1+i)-B_{\rm{in}}\approx 960.19$$
and the total profit is $P=\pi(B_{\rm{in}})+\pi(R_s)=2,500$.

If the bank use the simple interest rate $j$, then you have to find $j$ such that
$$
B_{\rm{in}}(1+j)+\underbrace{R_s\left(1+j\frac{5}{30}\right)-R_s}_{\pi(R_s)}=B_{\rm{in}}+P
$$
that is $$j=\frac{P}{B_{\rm{in}}+\frac{R_s}{6}}\approx 9.38\%$$
and $\pi(B_{\rm{in}})\approx 937.50$ and $\pi(R_s)\approx 1,562.50$.

Comment: Unfortunately, my algebra is weak. Well I understood your provided solution, but tried another (simplified) way and the answer matched your solution: 10,000*30days : 100,000*5days = 3 : 5; Now (2500/8) x 5 gives exactly 1,562.50. Could you confirm if this alternative approach will give correct results always.

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach is if you consider simple interest, not compound.  The  Rs $10,000$ represents $300,000$ Rs-days of deposit.  The Rs $100,000$ represents $500,000$ Rs-days of deposit.  So the $100,000$ should get $\frac 5{5+3}=\frac 58$ of the profit, ofr $\frac 58 \cdot 2500=1562.5$ As the duration is short and the profit is small compared to the amount, compounding will not matter much, as you can see from the other answer.